# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{a\sinh\left[\frac{p}{c}(L-x)\right]}{p\sinh\left[\frac{pL}{c}\right]}$ with respect to $p$ using binomial theorem

Tags: laplace-transform, binomial-theorem

I have the expression
$$\frac{a\sinh\left[\frac{p}{c}(L-x)\right]}{p\sinh\left[\frac{pL}{c}\right]}$$
and I want to find the inverse Laplace transform as an infinite series by using the binomial expansion. I tried rewriting the denominator as exponentials and expanding using the binomial theorem, but this gave me an infinite series of terms of the form $\exp\cdot\sinh$ which when inverse Laplace transformed gave me a delta function using the convolution theorem (which doesn't seem right - I don't think my answer should be an infinite sum of delta functions!).

How can I use the binomial theorem here?

Comment: 1) Do we agree that "p" is like "s", i.e., the Laplace variable. But in this case $a$,$x$,$L$ are constants ??? 2) Binomial expansion ? Are you sure it's not a Taylor expansion ? 3) The fact that you obtain a series of $\delta$s (you may know it is called a "Dirac comb") is not necessarily false. You should provide what you have obtained

Comment: @JeanMarie p is indeed the Laplace variable, and all other things are constants with respect to p. It is explicitly given that I should use the binomial theorem, although it is certainly possible I could combine it with Taylor expansions.

Comment: @JeanMarie We can write $\operatorname {csch} p$ as a geometric series of exponentials (convergent for $\operatorname {Re} p > 0$), which of course is a special case of the binomial series. Since there is a $p$ factor in the denominator, we get a sum of shifted unit step functions, or $\mathcal L^{-1}[p \mapsto p^{-1} \sinh(p + a) \operatorname {csch} p](t) = A \lfloor t/2 \rfloor + B$ for some constants $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Maxim I haven't had chance to go over the details, but it sounds like this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: @Maxim I don't understand. A geometric series isn't the same as a binomial expansion (think in particular to the factorials that aren't present in a geometic series).

Comment: @JeanMarie Consider what $\binom {-1} k$ simplifies to.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to the question but without any use of binomial theorem.

Let us use simplified notations:

$$F(s)=\frac{a}{p}\frac{\sinh(Ap-B)}{\sinh(Ap)}=
\frac{a}{p}\left(\frac{\sinh(Ap)\cosh(B)-\sinh(B)\cosh(Ap)}{\sinh(Ap)}\right)$$

$$F(s)=\frac{a}{p}\cosh(B)-a\sinh(B)\frac{1}{p}\operatorname{coth}(Ap)\tag{1}$$

Here, we can use the (ill-known) [series representation](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Coth/06/ShowAll.html):

$$\operatorname{coth}(X)=\frac1X + 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{X}{\pi^2n^2+X^2}$$

giving

$$\frac{1}{p}\operatorname{coth}(Ap)=\frac{1}{Ap^2} + 2A \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi^2n^2+(Ap)^2}\tag{2}$$

From there it is not difficult to obtain the inverse Laplace Transform of (2) due to classical formula:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{1}{k^2+p^2}=\frac1k \sin kt$$

under the form of an infinite series, in fact the Fourier series of a [sawtooth function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1948076).

But where is the Binomial Theorem hidden ?

Comment: Any comment ?... I have in fact given you an answer even if some little work is left... but I doubt more and more that there is a method using the binomial theorem, even the extended binomial theorem under the form $(1+X)^{\alpha}=1+\alpha X+\alpha( \alpha-1)/2 X^2+...$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a nice solution although I'll leave the question open as I'm looking for a solution using the binomial theorem.

Comment: There's a factor $A$ missing in Eq. (2). I tried to edit this but apparently edits need to be more than 6 characters..

Comment: Thanks @adriaanvalk

Comment: The edit is wrong, there's still a factor $A$ missing in the numerator of the last term of eq. (2) and the factor $p$ in denominator should not be there.

Comment: @adriaanvalk Yes you are right ! Fixed now...